# Make a Zip archive by clicking a button from PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, powerapp, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-functions

It will be great if you can select multiple items in a SharePoint Library an make a Zip archive by clicking a button from powerApps in SharePoint Online.

To download or Send to OneDrive or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PowerApps only supports the other way around, which is extracting an archive file into a SharePoint folder.

You can visit PowerApps Community and share this idea under PowerApps Ideas platform.

Reference:

[PowerApps delegable functions and operations for SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#powerapps-delegable-functions-and-operations-for-sharepoint)

[PowerApps Ideas.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/idb-p/PowerAppsIdeas)